# How to fix missing libLLVM-13.so libraries

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, llvm

I am using Arch Linux and I installed `llvm` using `sudo pacman -S llvm`.
I installed some programs like `ccls`, `clangd`, `cppcheck` etc. and none of them are working:

```
ccls: error while loading shared libraries: libLLVM-13.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

clangd: error while loading shared libraries: libLLVM-13.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

cppcheck: error while loading shared libraries: libtinyxml2.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to fix these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the package `llvm-libs`

https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/llvm-libs/

Comment: You might want to add to your answer *how* you figured this out (I'm assuming with `pacman -F filename`, correct?).

Comment: A look at the [package information](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/ccls/) for ccls and the other packages also provides the information that they need llvm-libs to work.